# How to show in the view the search results after the user click in the "Search" button?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a UserController with index() that returns to the view the conferences that have the status "D" (Draft), the past conferences and the published conferences.

In the view there is a form so the user can introduce a name to search for conference names created by the user.

My doubt is how to properly show in the view the search results after the user click in the "Search" button. Because as it is it appears "Undefined variable: searchedConferences".

UsersController:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){

        $pageLimit = 5;
        $user = $request->user();

        $draftConferences = $user->conferences()->where('status','D')->paginate($pageLimit);
        $pastConferences = $user->conferences()->where('end_date','<', now())->paginate($pageLimit);
        $publishedConferences = $user->conferences()->where('status','P')->paginate($pageLimit);

        return view('users.index',
            compact('user', 'draftConferences', 'pastConferences', 'publishedConferences'));
    }
    public function searchConference(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $search = $request->search_conference;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->where('creator_id',$user->id)->get();

        //dd($conferences);
       return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#myConferences')->with('searchedConferences', $conferences);
    }
}
```

Then in the view I have a form for a user to search for conferences. And belo the form it appears the data returned from the index(). There are 3 tabs (Draft Conferences, Published conferences, Finished Conferences), by default appears active the Draft Conferences tab. When the user click in another tab it appears in the tab content the results of that specific tab (past conferences, draft conferences or finsih conferences).

```
<form method="post" method="POST" action="{{ route('user.searchConference') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">

      <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Search conferences" name="search_conference"/>
      <button>Search</button>

    </div>
</form>

@if(!empty($searchedConferences))
            {{$searchedConferences}}
        @else
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active border" href="#draftConferences" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Draft Conferences</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link border" href="#publishedConferences" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Published Conferences</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link border" href="#finishedConferences" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Conferences Archived</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active show clearfix" id="draftConferences" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($draftConferences as $draftConference)
                        @if(!empty($draftConference))
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                 <h5>{{$draftConference->name}}</h5>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                   <div>
                        {{$draftConferences->fragment('draftConferences')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- same structure for the "#publishedConferences" and "#finishedConferences" -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the reidrect()->with() puts the data from the with() method into session. I would change the redirect part completely to serve the view with the new items or change your variable on the blade to what it is in the session. Probably something like:

`{{ \Session::get('searchedConferences') }}`

See 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-redirect-with-variables?page=1 it's where I found some useful information there for this question.